# How to control time activated display update

Tags: android, user-interface

I am looking for the method to update the screen at a constant rate, say every 50mSec.
In the embedded world I would configure a timer to trigger an interrupt every 50mSec and the ISR would handle the update. What I have in mind for Android is to have a FrameLayout with a number of view items registered to react to some sort of callback from a timer function.

Hopefully someone will understand my question and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try using timers and calling OnCreate() method when the time ends.

Comment: @superM there is a lot of comment warning against the use of timers. I am wondering if there are better options.

Comment: Most of trouble comes when you use timers with multiple threads. If the timer and OnCreate() run in the same thread I don't think there would be any much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `handler.postDelayed` in a `Runnable` to call it after certain time period.

For example:

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
            //do your task
        }
    });
```

Make sure you handler is attached to a separate (non-UI) thread and when it comes to update UI elements you always do it on a UI thread.

Comment: I saw a few postings related to this and could not get my head around it. Do you know of any good references that might help clear the fog in my head?

Comment: yes, read this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Thanks, I have read it now need to digest it and then experiment. Seems to have something missing, the notes say "To do this, just put another postDelayed at the tail of the mUpdateTimeTask run() method." but then it is not included in the code sample. Oversite I guess.

Comment: Finally got time to test this and it works fine. Thanks again.